# optional character with MaskFormatter java

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield, maskformatter

I need a simple thing.

I have a `JFormattedTextField` with `MaskFormatter` "##" but I want the first digit is optional.

The information I want to get is the day of the month.

Thanks.